# Is it possible to connect to 2010 TFS from Visual Studio 2008 Professional

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to connect to 2010 TFS from Visual Studio 2008 Professional

There is an update VS90SP1-KB974558-x86.exe that is targeting VS2008 client, but that update did not recognize Professional version of VS2008.

Although TFS2010 is part of professional MSDN subscription

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [blog post](http://ammarcool.blogspot.com/2010/03/vs2008-professional-connecting-to-tfs.html) should get you going.

Quoted from post:

> 1. You have to install Team Explorer 2008 over your VS2008 Professional
>      SP1.
> 2. You need to reinstall VS2008SP1 to update team explorer.
> 3. After that you have to install Visual Studio Team System 2008 Service
>      Pack 1 Forward Compatibility Update
>      for Team Foundation Server 2010
>      (Installer) from this link.
> 4. When you connect from VS2008, you need to enter the full URL (ex:http://tfs2010:8080/tfs)

[The order is important](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/salvapatuel/archive/2009/07/24/accessing-tfs-2010-from-vs2008.aspx) and [you have to enter the full URL in 08](http://www.kulov.net/blogs/martin/2009/05/connect-to-tfs-2010-from-vs2008.html).